# How to inject service as argument in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection

What is the correct way in Symfony to override the parent service argument and also add to the children more arguments? According to the documentation, I need to use "index_N". But how to add more arguments to the child service? In example:

## config/services.yaml

services:
    # ...

```
App\Repository\DoctrineUserRepository:
    parent: App\Repository\BaseDoctrineRepository

    # overrides the public setting of the parent service
    public: false

    # appends the '@app.username_checker' argument to the parent
    # argument list
    arguments: ['@app.username_checker']

App\Repository\DoctrinePostRepository:
    parent: App\Repository\BaseDoctrineRepository

    # overrides the first argument (using the special index_N key)
    arguments:
        index_0: '@doctrine.custom_entity_manager'
        // put here more arguments for the child service
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but did you try using "named arguments", like here:

```
# overrides the first argument (using the special index_N key)
# and set named argument $usernameChecker
arguments:
    index_0: '@doctrine.custom_entity_manager'
    $usernameChecker: '@app.username_checker'
```

Comment: The name should be equal to the variable name that I pass to the constructor, right?

Comment: Yes. https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments